# copying Folder to another folder which copy all content recursively

Tags: android

i want to copy folder1 to the folder2.now folder1 consists of many folders and files also and so on..How can i program that all the files and folders will copy to the Folder2.I know the logic to copy a single file to a folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar problems in other platforms often use [recursion](http://www.danzig.us/java_class/recursion.html).

Answer (score 1):

Save some time and use the [Jakarta FileUtils.copyDirectory()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)